# Will it work to pass a reference to a base class to boost::thread, and have virtual functions in the derived class called?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-thread

Suppose I have:

```
class Base
{
    public:

        void operator()()
        {
            this->run();
        }

        virtual void run () {}
}

class Derived : public Base
{
    public:

        virtual void run ()
        {
            // Will this be called when the boost::thread runs?
        }
}

int main()
{
    Base * b = new Derived();
    boost::thread t(*b); // <-- which "run()" function will be called - Base or Derived?
    t.join();
    delete b;
}
```

From my tests, I cannot get `Derived::run()` to be called.  Am I doing something wrong, or is this impossible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@GManNickG's comment is the cleanest answer, and works perfectly.  Boost.Ref is the way to go.

```
thread t(boost::ref(*b));
```

Answer (score 2):

By passing `*b` you actually "slice" `Derived` object, i.e. pass `Base` instance by value.
You should pass `Derived` functor by pointer (or smart-pointer), like this:

```
thread t(&Derived::operator(), b); // boost::bind is used here implicitly
```

Of course, pay attention to the `b` lifetime.